# Recursive functions for sequences in F#

Tags: recursion, f#, sequence

Rather trivial question, but a quick google search didn't give me the answer.

What is a standard way to write a recursive functions for sequences? For lists you would do pattern matching with empty list and head+tail pattern, what is the equivalent for sequences?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no standard way to do so since you rarely write recursive functions for sequences.

You should look at a variety of high-order functions in [Seq module](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353635.aspx). They are often more than adequate, so you don't have to write recursive functions by yourself.

To generate sequences recursively, sequence expression is a simple and intuitive way to go:

```
let rec allFiles dir =
    seq { yield! Directory.GetFiles dir
          for d in Directory.GetDirectories dir do
            yield! allFiles d }
```

If you have to break down a sequence and manipulate it recursively, you are doing it wrong. You should either manipulate `List` or [LazyList from F# PowerPack](http://fsharppowerpack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/68767#685030), and convert results back to sequences.

Comment: Let me ask a more specific question then :)

Comment: Yes, that would be great. It is difficult to answer this question without specific details.

Comment: Asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11452142/drawing-a-random-number-from-a-discrete-distribution-function-stored-as-a-sequen

Comment: Anyway, I am rather surprised that there is no easy way to get hold of the (immutable) iterator over the sequence.

Comment: Answered your question there. You can always use `GetEnumerator()`, but it's imperative and error-prone.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to get the tail of a sequence because it has not been evaluated (and could in theory be infinite), so you cannot pass the tail into a function recursively. You would just use Seq.iter or yield! to go through the sequence.

Comment: You can do `Seq.skip 1` which will mark that *once the items are evaluated* a single item will be skipped.