# Decorate an F# sequence with (simple) computed state for each element

Tags: f#

I have a solution to this, and several working-but-unsatisfactory solutions, but it took a lot of work and seems unnecessarily complex.

Am I missing something in F#?

**The Problem**

I have a sequence of numbers

```
let nums = seq { 9; 12; 4; 17; 9; 7; 13; }
```

I want to decorate each number with an "index", so the result is

```
seq [(9, 0); (12, 1); (4, 2); (17, 3); ...]
```

Looks simple!

In practice the input can be very large and of indeterminate size. In my application, it is coming from a REST service.

Further

- the operation must support lazy evaluation (because of the REST backend)
- must be purely functional, which eliminates the obvious `seq { let mutable i = o; for num in nums do .. }` solution, ditto for `while ... do ...`

Lets call the function `decorate`, of type `(seq<'a> -> seq<'a * int>)`, so it would work as follows:

```
nums
|> decorate
|> Seq.iter (fun (n,index) -> printfn "%d: %d" index n)
```

Producing:

```
0: 9
1: 12
2: 4
...
6: 13
```

This is a trivial problem with Lists (apart from the lazy evaluation), but tricky with Sequences.

My solution is to use Seq.unfold, as follows:

```
let decorate numSeq = 
    (0,numSeq) 
    |> Seq.unfold 
        (fun (count,(nums : int seq)) -> 
            if Seq.isEmpty nums then
                None
            else
                let result = ((Seq.head nums),count)
                let remaining = Seq.tail nums
                Some( result, (count+1,remaining)))
```

This meets all requirements, and is the best I've come up with.

Here's the whole solution, with diagnostics to show lazy evaluation:

```
let nums = 
    seq {
        // With diagnostic
        let getN n =
            printfn "get: %d" n
            n

        getN 9; 
        getN 12; 
        getN 4; 
        getN 17; 
        getN 9; 
        getN 7; 
        getN 13 
    }
    
let decorate numSeq = 
    (0,numSeq) 
    |> Seq.unfold 
        (fun (count,(nums : int seq)) -> 
            if Seq.isEmpty nums then
                None
            else
                let result = ((Seq.head nums),count)
                let remaining = Seq.tail nums
                printfn "unfold: %A" result
                Some( result, (count+1,remaining)))

nums
|> Seq.cache 
    // To prevent re-computation of the sequence.
    // Will be necessary for any solution. This solution required only one.
|> decorate
|> Seq.iter (fun (n,index) -> printfn "ITEM %d: %d" index n)
```

**PROBLEM:** This took a LOT of work to reach. It looks complex, compared to the (apparently) simple requirement.

**QUESTION:** Is there a simpler solution?

---

*Discussion of some alternatives.*

All work, but are unsatisfactory for the reasons given

```
// Most likely: Seq.mapFold
// Fails lazy evalation. The final state must be evaluated, even if not used
let decorate numSeq = 
    numSeq
    |> Seq.mapFold 
        (fun count num -> 
            let result = (num,count)
            printfn "yield: %A" result
            (result,(count + 1)))
        0
    |> fun (nums,finalState) -> nums // And, no, using "_" doesn't fix it!


// 'for' loop, with MUTABLE
// Lazy evaluation works
// Not extensible, as the state 'count' is specific to this problem
let decorate numSeq =
    let mutable count = 0
    seq { 
        for num in numSeq do 
            let result = num,count
            printfn "yield: %A" result
            yield result; 
            count <- count+1
    }

// 'for' loop, without mutable
// Fails lazy evaluation, and is ugly 
let decorate numSeq =
    seq {
        for index in 0..((Seq.length numSeq) - 1) do
            let result = ((Seq.item index numSeq), // Ugly!
                            index) 
            printfn "yield: %A" result
            yield result
    }

// "List" like recursive descent, 
// Fails lazy evaluation. Ugly, because we are not meant to use recursion on Sequences
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11451727/recursive-functions-for-sequences-in-f
let rec decorate' count (nums : int seq) =
    if Seq.isEmpty nums then
        Seq.empty
    else
        let hd = Seq.head nums
        let tl = Seq.tail nums
        let result = (hd,count)
        let tl' = decorate' (count+1) tl
        printfn "yield: %A" result
        seq { yield result; yield! tl'}

let decorate : (seq<'a> -> seq<'a * int>) = decorate' 0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Seq.mapi` to do what you need.

```
let nums = seq { 9; 12; 4; 17; 9; 7; 13; }
nums |> Seq.mapi (fun i num  -> (num, i))
```

This gives `(9, 0); (12, 1); etc...`

`Seq` is "lazy" in the same sense as `IEnumerable` in C#.

You can read about `Seq.mapi` here:

https://fsharp.github.io/fsharp-core-docs/reference/fsharp-collections-seqmodule.html#mapi

Read more about the use of `map` here:

https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/elevated-world/#map

Comment: Thankyou! A great answer! Looks like the approved answer, unless someone else comes up with something stunning.

Comment: Tomas below provided an even simpler solution - just a single function `Seq.indexed`, which returns the required tuples, albeit in order `(index,num)`, but this solution meets my stated requirements *exactly*, and also is considerably simpler than my `Seq.unfold`, as requested. It is also extensible, hence answering my title of "(Simple) computed state". So, this is the accepted answer.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the `Seq.mapi` function mentioned in Sean's answer, F# also has a built-in `Seq.indexed` function, which decorates a sequence with index. This does not do exactly what you're asking, because the index becomes the first element of the tuple, but depending on your use case, it may do the trick:

```
> let nums = seq { 9; 12; 4; 17; 9; 7; 13; };;
val nums : seq<int>

> Seq.indexed nums;;
val it : seq<int * int> = seq [(0, 9); (1, 12); (2, 4); (3, 17); ...]
```

If I was trying to implement this on my own using a more primitive function, it could be done using `Seq.scan`, which is a bit like fold but produces a lazy sequence of states. The only tricky thing is that you have to construct the initial state and then process the rest of the sequence:

```
Seq.tail nums 
|> Seq.scan (fun (prevIndex, _) v -> (prevIndex+1, v)) (0, Seq.head nums)
```

This will not work for empty lists, even though the function should logically be able to handle this.

Comment: Another great answer, which: 1. Provides an even simpler solution than mapi (ie. `indexed`) and 2. Provides a more primitive solution (ie. `scan`), and hence more extensible. Unfortunately, for myself and the two respondents, the simpler solution doesn't meet my specified requirements *exactly*, where `mapi` does, so there's difficulty in approving it as the accepted answer. I note that `indexed` puts the index first in the tuple, and as F# functions are always carefully constructed to be idiomatic, this is probably better idiom than my requirement. Regretfully, I can't accept both answers :(

Comment: There was also implied in my question for the solution to be "extensible", because obviously I'm not really just reading a sequence of numbers with REST and indexing them! Both solutions (`mapi`) and your `scan` are extensible, with `mapi` being more simple if only interested in the current element and index, where `scan` supports cumulative values (but is, as you say, tricky to initialise). Again, while this may be the more useful in many instances, `mapi` is closest to my stated requirement of "(simple) computed state", so is Accepted. However, thanks so much for such an illuminating answer!

Answer (score 1):

1. Using `for` is not bad, or wrong. `for` and `yield` in a `seq {}` is how you write new `seq` functions, if none of the provided functions in `Seq` Module is a best-fit. It is neither wrong, or bad to use this special construct. It's the same as C# `foreach` and `yield` syntax.
2. Using a mutable in a limited scope, is also not wrong. Mutables are a bad idea, if they escape the scope. For example, you return a mutable value, from a function.
3. Its important to put the mutable inside the `seq`, and not outside. Your version is wrong.

Let's assume this

```
let xs = decorate [3;6;7;12;9]

for x in xs do
    printfn "%A" x

for x in xs do
    printfn "%A" x
```

Now you have two versions of decorate. The first version

```
let decorate numSeq = 
    let mutable count = 0
    seq { 
        for num in numSeq do 
            yield (num,count)
            count <- count + 1
    }
```

will print:

```
(3, 0)
(6, 1)
(7, 2)
(12, 3)
(9, 4)
(3, 5)
(6, 6)
(7, 7)
(12, 8)
(9, 9)
```

Or in other words. The mutable is shared across all invocation whenever you iterate through the sequence. As a general tip. If you want to return a `seq` then put all your code into `seq`. And put the `seq {}` after the `=` sign. If you do this instead.

```
let decorate numSeq = seq { 
    let mutable count = 0
    for num in numSeq do 
        yield (num,count)
        count <- count + 1
}
```

you get the correct output:

```
(3, 0)
(6, 1)
(7, 2)
(12, 3)
(9, 4)
(3, 0)
(6, 1)
(7, 2)
(12, 3)
(9, 4)
```

Forther you explain, that this version is not "extensible". But the version with `mapi` you select as "correct". Has the same problem, it only provides an index, nothing more.

If you want a more generic version, you *always* can make a function that expects its values as a function argument. You could for example change the above function to this code.

```
let decorate2 f (state:'State) (xs:'T seq) = seq {
    let mutable state = state
    for x in xs do
        yield state, x
        let newState = f state x
        state <- newState
}
```

Now `decorate2` expects a state that you can freely pass, and a function to change the state. With this function you could then write:

```
decorate2 (fun state _ -> state+1) 0 [3;6;7;12;9]
```

The function signature is nearly the same as `Seq.scan`, but still a little bit different. But if you want to create a `indexed` function, you could use `scan` like this.

```
let indexed xs =
    Seq.scan (fun (count,_) x -> (count+1,x)) (0,Seq.head xs) (Seq.skip 1 xs)
```

Just in my opinion. This version is harder rot read, understand, and just fugly compared to `decorate` or `decorate2`.

And just a note. There is already a `Seq.indexed` function in the standard library, that does what you wish.

```
for x in Seq.indexed [3;6;7;12;9] do
    printfn "%A" x
```

will print

```
(0, 3)
(1, 6)
(2, 7)
(3, 12)
(4, 9)
```